# Android repeating bitmap border

Tags: android, listview, border, drawable

Exist any way to do ListView with hand-writed border. Something like this? 
[Visit](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4cvGZEUKRVk/UJdA7gxD34I/AAAAAAAABLk/yYvdR7rwOVU/s640/thanksgiving.jpg)
Where the center of the frame will be repeated.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Nine path is not helpful for this. I need something like 9-path with repeating. Or drawable with bitmap corners and bitmap border that will not stretch but repeated. I will need this border for EditTexts, ListViews and buttons with different sizes. But I dont't know if it's possible. I have no code yet.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just add PNGs for different screen-sizes and densities.

Comment: Yes but the views may increase with lot of text.

Comment: It's possible or I must change graphics?